# Insert icon inside input without breaking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sAKz.png

Basicly i have an input and i want to add that icon to it in order to display a tooltip once the user hover it. My main problem knowing the best practice in order to insert that icon inside the input without breaking html structures ( either the responsive ones or really old ones ).

EDIT1:
This is the logic i've been trying to use.

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  }

.myImage{
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;
  right:5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <img class="myImage" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/16/information-icon.png">
  </div>
```

I'm developing a plugin where i receive the fields id and then create the icons inside those inputs so later i can show a tooltip.

I've tried to go to a website which had older structured forms instead of responsive ones. And few of them got broken in terms of display using "display:inline-block".

PS: My problem is setting the wrapper div + display:inline-block in some older structured forms, which in some of them after applying those properties they stay broken (outside of original position) .

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: @jbutler483 Pseudo elements (like `:after` and `:before`) are a good option. Another option is to overlay a `position:absolute` element over the field. Make sure to search before asking, as it's very likely this question has already come up several times in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `pseudo element` to achieve this sort of functionality. Since the

> pseudo elements cannot be placed directly onto an input tag

, i've wrapped the input in a div and placed the pseudo on it instead:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cp3 input {
  width: 50px;
}
input {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cp4 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.cp4:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/64494.png);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="label">Postal Code</div>

  <div class="cp4">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="cp3">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

</div>
```

---

## You want a tooltip?

---

Using an absolutely positioned element, you can then use the [`~` (sibling selector)](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) to show a tooltip as well when you hover the icon.

To get any sort of 'fade in' using css, I've applied the `opacity:0 --> opacity:1` with a nice transition. This can be shown in the below example:

```css
.myInput {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.myInput div,
input {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
.tooltip {
    transition: all 0.8s;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/64494.png);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  right: 0;
  top:5%;
}

.myInput:hover .tooltip{
  opacity:1;
  }

.tooltip:hover ~.msg{
  opacity:1;
  }
.msg{
  transition: all 0.8s;
  top:35px;
  left:100px;
  opacity:0;
  }
.toRight{
  top:0;
  left:220px;
  width:300px;
  }
```

```html
Hover the textbox, then the icon
<br/>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div class="myInput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text here" />
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="msg">message here</div>
  <div class="msg toRight">Or even here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @jbutler483 , that is sort of the same logic i've been trying to use. Which is having a div wrapped around my input, and then insert the image inside of my wrapped div and set position:relative;display:inline-block to wrapper and absolute to my image, and set its position. My main problem is i've tried using the same logic in pages which have older structured forms and some of them got broken in terms of display.

I'm developing a plugin to insert those icons into inputs targeted by user. So i dont have control of the page, only elements.

Comment: @user1195961: please explain. If this didn't work, you need to clarify what's not working, plus I'd like to add, it would be good of you (if applicable) for you to accept answers for your prevoius questions (press the white tick on the left hand side of your chosen answer)

Comment: i've added more information to the main post. I'm sorry for the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

this is the css

```
#icn{
    background-image:url(http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/System/Dustbunnies%20Full/info.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    background-size:12px 12px;
    padding-right:15px;

}
```

and this is your html example:

```
<input id="icn" type="text">
```

i have set the image how background

http://jsfiddle.net/kx6s5yfs/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="postalcode" class="postalcode" />

.postalcode{
    background-image: url("abc.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code. If this answers the OP's question and he can understand this code; why would he not have written it himself?